# Scala / Akka - pass message through behavior stack?

Tags: scala, akka

If I've stacked up behavior via `context become(foo, discardOld = false)`, is there a way to defer a message to further down the behavior stack?

Let's say I have stacked contexts `foo` and `bar`.  Both have some handling for the `Baz` message (among others) - if `foo` is on the top of the behavior stack, is there a way for it to pass the `Baz` message on to `bar`?

I suppose that `case` guards would prevent one level from consuming the message, but that would still make side-effects more complicated at the `foo` level before passing on the message -- the guard would have to be some function which executed the side effect.

EDIT AS TO WHEREFOR:

I've used the stacked contexts as a (sort of) alternative to a class hierarchy.  There's some base behavior shared by all of these actors in lower level contexts, then additional behavior in a layer added after that which differentiates the actors.  It's a "sort of" alternative, because the actors may actually need to change "class" in response to messages (while preserving self, so that other actors with a handle to these don't need to replace a bunch of refs, etc).  What I'd like to be able to do is akin to conditionally calling `super.apply(Baz)` while maintaining side-effects in the right conceptual layer / location.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Stash Trait (http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/actor/Stash.html) and stash all the messages of a particular kind. You can then unstash all the stashed messages and process them with your "new" (lower in the stack) receive behavior after unbecoming the behavior that wasn't meant to process them.  This doesn't sound like exactly what you want, but could be useful.

In response to your edits:

If you want a base actor and then have actors that slightly modify the receive method of the base actor you can use abstract overrides.  This is COMPLETELY different that stacked receives but should accomplish what you are looking for:

```
class Base extends Actor {
   def receive {
      case Baz => println("BASIC BEHAVIOR") 
      case _ => println("other messages")
   }
}

trait BaseWithOtherWayToHandleBaz extends Base {
   def otherRecieve: Recieve = {
     case Baz => println("OVERRIDE BEHAVIOR")
   }

   abstract override def receive = otherRecieve orElse super.receieve
}
```

Comment: hrm, maybe.  However, I'd definitely like to preserve the top of the stack rather than `unbecome`ing it.

Comment: What is the use of your stacked behavior right now?  Are you ever unbecoming?

Comment: well, slight mod: the actors do occasionally unbecome, but not in the context of the messages that would be handed off.  Q also updated.

Comment: re your edits: that doesn't seem to accomplish persistent actors that morph between different traits.  It also can't conditionally pass `Baz` from otherReceive to super.receive.

Comment: not exactly sure how to help you... you might be looking for this design pattern: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fsm.html

Answer (score 0):

`Receive` is a `PartialFunction` and you can use `orElse` or `andThen` to compose them.

Comment: I don't think `andThen` is going to be useful on `Receive` - it yields `Unit`.  `orElse` doesn't cover the "evaluate in this chunk *and* this one" case.